# Conditional formatting in google sheet not working for duplicates

Tags: gs-conditional-formatting

I'm trying to add conditional formatting to highlight rows that have duplicate values. I followed direction from other questions/forums:

Format>Conditional formatting>

- Single Color
- Apply to range = A1:A988
- Format rules = Custom formula is COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1
- Formating style = Fill color light green

However, none of the rows with duplicate values are being highlighted.

[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13EKfWxkgAc6i3I3laVJTpKvHd5Z2cqDrS2H7fwu_8sQ/edit?usp=sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Va6kp.png)

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Va6kp.png)

[Conditional Format Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRQ6h.png)

Comment: Wow, I'm so embarrassed! Really wishing I had a google sheets expert close to me to be able to bounce these kind of questions off of, haha. Thanks!!

Comment: Neither working for me...

Answer (score 2):

Your formula is correct, probably you missed to put `=` initially, so your formula would be `=COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1`

[image: result1]  [image: formula1]

Answer (score 1):

This answer is coming too late to help you as its been years. However I had the same problem and just figured it out. I found I couldn't have the full column as the first value inside the parenthesis. It needed to match the range I was applying the formula too. So in the case of your example it needs to be =COUNTIF(A1:A988,A1)>1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try =COUNTIF(A:A;A1)>1

Comment: I initially thought this was the same solution as in Shiva's answer. But what you're saying if that they should use `;` instead of `,` in their formula? Sorry I'm not familiar with the technology, just trying to clarify things. Thanks.

Comment: Note to reviewers: the explanation in my edit suggestion rejection was inaccurate. Sorry about that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).